# OrmLite SQL expression query with type converter

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am testing some features of OrmLite with a little example and have found a different behaviour between the SQL expressions API and the raw SQL one while using type converters.

I have 2 domain classes:

```
public class Account : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Money Balance { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

public class Currency : Unit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    public Currency(string format)
    {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public static implicit operator string (Currency value)
    {
        return value.Symbol;
    }

    public static implicit operator Currency(string value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case "EUR":
                return Euro;
            case "USD":
                return Dollar;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    private static Currency euro = new Currency("{0:n2} €") { Name = "Euro", Symbol = "EUR" };
    private static Currency dollar = new Currency("${0:n2}") { Name = "Dollar", Symbol = "USD" };

    public static Currency Euro
    {
        get
        {
            return euro;
        }
    }

    public static Currency Dollar
    {
        get
        {
            return dollar;
        }
    }
}
```

A type converter:

```
public class CurrencyConverter : OrmLiteConverter
{
    public override string ColumnDefinition { get { return "char(3)"; } }

    public override DbType DbType { get { return DbType.StringFixedLength; } }

    public override object ToDbValue(Type fieldType, object value)
    {
        return (value as Currency).Symbol;
    }

    public override object FromDbValue(Type fieldType, object value)
    {
        Currency currency = value as string;
        return currency;
    }
}
```

And a test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);

        SqlServerDialect.Provider.RegisterConverter<Money>(new MoneyConverter());
        SqlServerDialect.Provider.RegisterConverter<Currency>(new CurrencyConverter());

        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.Open())
        {
            db.DropAndCreateTable<Account>();

            var account = new Account()
            {
                Name = "My account",
                Currency = Currency.Dollar,
                Balance = 200
            };

            db.Save(account);

            // Raw SQL get the correct value
            var result = db.Single<Account>("Currency = @currency", new { currency = Currency.Dollar });
            // SQL expression gets null
            var otherResult = db.Single<Account>(x => x.Currency == Currency.Dollar);
        }
    }
```

I expected to receive the same result on both Single calls, but it seems the SQL expression query is not using the type converter to get the value of the parameter.

Is there any way of achieving this behaviour with SQL Expressions?

Comment: did you try to register converters before creation of factory?

Comment: Tried right now, same result. Raw SQL is using the type converter but SQL Expression not.

Comment: Have you tryed to get all records? what Currency in that case?

Comment: Using Select instead of Single I get the same results, raw SQL gets 1 'Account' populated correctly but SQL Expression gets 0 results.

Comment: Is select without where gets 0 records?

Comment: db.Select<Account>() gets 1 record but i'm testing db.Select<Account>(x => x.Currency == Currency.Dollar) which returns 0 records

Comment: Could you explore value of field Currency of record you get with db.Select<Account>()?

Comment: It's equal to Currency.Dollar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typed SqlExpression uses inline SQL instead of parameterized queries by default which calls your TypeConverter's `ToQuotedString()` API.

You can instead enable preview support for using parameterized queries in SQL Expressions for SQL Server and Oracle by setting:

```
OrmLiteConfig.UseParameterizeSqlExpressions = true;
```

Comment: It works ok in version 4.0.52, even without setting OrmLiteConfig.UseParameterizeSqlExpressions = true, thanks!

Comment: @JorgeVilluendas that's because [Parameterized SqlExpressions is now the default behavior in v4.0.52](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/release-notes.md#parameterized-sql-expressions) :)